# neo4j query regarding schema and recommendation

Tags: neo4j, schema, recommendation-engine

I have 3 tables
`user-friend(userID,friendID)` "friendID is actually userID which is friend of userID",
`artist(artistID,name,url,picurl)`,
`user-artist(userID,artistID,count)`

I need to design neo4j schema which implements below query.

find all artist listened by a user's friends but not the user,oredr them by the sum of friends' listening counts,recommend the top 5.

Comment: And what's your question ? What's  your current schema, what is the blocking point ?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question so that we can help you better?

Answer (score 1):

That's a classic query, you find it in the [online training](http://neo4j.com/online-training) and here too:

http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-build-a-recommendation-engine/